# Windows PowerShell DSC without ensure property

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

May I know in the following PowerShell DSC, what is the difference if I remove the Ensure property (not ensure attribute)?

In another sense, any default if no value specified for Ensure property?

```
Node WebServer
{
WindowsFeature IIS {
Ensure = "Present",
Name = "Web–Server"
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by Ensure property vs Ensure attribute, but the default value is `Present`. You can see in the [documentation for the DSC WindowsFeature Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/windowsfeatureresource) that `Ensure` is not required; `Name` is the only required property:

> ```
> WindowsFeature [string] #ResourceName
> {
>     Name = [string]
>     [ Credential = [PSCredential] ]
>     [ Ensure = [string] { Absent | Present }  ]
>     [ IncludeAllSubFeature = [bool] ]
>     [ LogPath = [string] ]
>     [ DependsOn = [string[]] ]
>     [ Source = [string] ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi mate, sorry and I meant to say Ensure property.  Thanks very much.  Now it is optional, I checked the link and it didn't specify the default value for properties like Ensure and IncludeAllSubFeature(whether it is true or false). Where can i find the documentation for the defaults value of IncludeAllSubFeature? Thanks heaps.

Comment: @anIBMer unfortunately I wasn't actually able to find that. But I know from experience that `Present` is the default, and the `xWindowsFeature` resource is a community resource so it's open source and available on GitHub, and it does set the default to `Present`.

Answer (score 0):

To **add** the role or feature (default):

`Ensure = 'Present'`

To **remove** the role or feature:

`Ensure = 'Absent'`